# Oversized image in html table

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to create a table in html with two columns. The first is an image and the second is accompanying text.

The image I use is small, so I decided to stretch it. But when I stretch the image, the td doesn't stretch accordingly (the height increases, but the width doesn't).

Because of this, the image from the first column overlaps with the text from the second. Does anyone have advice for making the table cell resize to fit the image?

Thanks!

Here's the CSS:

```
table
{
width: 100%;
}

td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    width: auto;
 }

#img1
{
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150%;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap><img id="im1" src="../images/dragon.gif" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="text-quote">

                    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

                </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note you can set an images `height` and `width` directly.

Comment: Since image is an inline element, the container does not stretch as per image size. You need to specify "display:inline-block" for the image.

Answer (score 1):

Well. You are giving the image a width of 150% so obviously is 150% of the container which, in this case, is the table cell so it displays correctly.

If you want to make the image bigger, Increase the width of the `<TD>` and give to your image a width of 100% (so it will take 100% of the td width)

```
.imageTD {width:150%;}
#im1 {
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/2dapa115/)

Comment: Or specify the image width in px